# Only Pulling Last Item from Tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a script that loops through multiple webpages, but there is one small issue that I am stuck on.  I am trying to add the author to the list but my script pulls the last author from the page and applies it to every author field.  How do I get my script to apply each author to the relevant title?  Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

base_url = "https://archive.org/details/librivoxaudio?&sort=titleSorter"

data = []
n = 5
for i in range(1, n+1):
   response = urlopen(base_url + "&page=" + str(i))
   page_html = response.read()
   response.close()

   #html parsing
   page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

   #grabs info for each book
   containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-ttl"})
   authors = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"byv"})

   for container in containers:
     item = {}
     item['type'] = "Public Domain Audiobook"
     item['title'] = container.text.lstrip().strip()
     for author in authors:
         item['author'] = author.text
     item['link'] = "https://archive.org/" + container.a["href"]
     item['source'] = "LibriVox"
     item['base_url'] = "https://librivox.org/"
     data.append(item) # add the item to the list

     with open("./json/librivoxTest.json", "w") as writeJSON:
       json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Here is a sample of the output in JSON

```
{
"type": "Public Domain Audiobook",
"title": "A Book of Old English Ballads",
"author": "Charles Whibley",
"link": "https://archive.org//details/book_old_english_ballads_1007_librivox",
"source": "LibriVox",
"base_url": "https://librivox.org/"
}, {
"type": "Public Domain Audiobook",
"title": "A Book of Scoundrels",
"author": "Charles Whibley",
"link": "https://archive.org//details/scoundrels_1712_librivox",
"source": "LibriVox",
"base_url": "https://librivox.org/"
}
```

The last author is correct for 'A Book of Scoundrels' but 'A Book of Old English Ballads' should have George Wharton Edwards as the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the below script will fix the issues you are having. I tried to make it in a slightly organized manner.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import json

urls = ["https://archive.org/details/librivoxaudio?&sort=titleSorter&page={}".format(page) for page in range(1,3)]

for link in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(link).read(), "html.parser")
    data = []
    for container in soup.select("div[data-id$='_librivox']"):
         item = {}
         item['type'] = "Public Domain Audiobook"
         item['title'] = container.select_one(".ttl").get_text(strip=True)
         item['author'] = container.select_one(".byv").get_text(strip=True) if container.select_one(".byv") else ""
         item['link'] = urljoin(link, container.select_one("a[title]")['href']) if container.select_one("a[title]") else ""
         item['source'] = "LibriVox"
         item['base_url'] = "https://librivox.org/"
         data.append(item)

    print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

Output are like:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Public Domain Audiobook",
        "title": "\"BOOH!\"",
        "author": "Eugene Field",
        "link": "https://archive.org/details/booh_1403.poem_librivox",
        "source": "LibriVox",
        "base_url": "https://librivox.org/"
    },
    {
        "type": "Public Domain Audiobook",
        "title": "\"You Bid Me Try\"",
        "author": "Henry Austin Dobson",
        "link": "https://archive.org/details/youbid_metry_1104_librivox",
        "source": "LibriVox",
        "base_url": "https://librivox.org/"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

`for author in authors:
         item['author'] = author.text`

This loops through all authors, and sets them to be the author of the item. The last author will be set for the item in the end.

To set the corresponding author instead, either use a generator on the authors (`authors_iterator = iter(authors)`, then for the item, set `next(authors_iterator)`), or use enumerate for looping through the containers, and use its index on the authors.